# Bibliography 1 not mentioned in text

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

For some reason, in my bibliography, the first reference is "not mentioned in text" and starts working normally at reference [2]. Does anyone know what may be causing it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se Without showing us how you are creating the bibliography, it's almost impossible to help you. In particular the  "Mentioned on page ..." annotations don't seem to be part of any standard bibliography package. Additionally, "Not mentioned on the text" would need to use "in" not "on" to be idiomatic English, again leading me to think that this is coming from a  custom package, class or `.bst` file somewhere.

Comment: Did you try adding `\nocite(*)`?